# decrease mount point partition

Tags: mountpoint

The mounting point / partition only uses a small fraction (7%) of the 132 GB originally allocated by the Ubuntu installer. Can I safely reallocate space from the / partition to the /home partition? can I reduce / to 32 GB and add 100 GB to /home?

Thanks for ur input :>)

Answer (score 1):

The program you are looking for is called gparted.  You will need to boot the live cd and launch it from there.